# Parallel timer creation crashes kernel

Tags: c, parallel-processing, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I've added a timer to kernel module responsible for TCP sockets creation in order to monitor its parameters. Everything works as it should until i want to invoke parallel connections - instant crash.

This is how i do it:

global var:

```
struct timer_list ss_timer;
```

in module register function:

```
init_timer(&ss_timer);
```

in module unregister function:

```
del_timer_sync(&ss_timer);
```

in function initiating TCP session establishement (invoked once per TCP connection, runs in parallel for multiple connections):

```
ss_timer.function = ss_timer_callback;
ss_timer.data = (unsigned long)&meta_sk;
ss_timer.expires = jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(500);
add_timer(&ss_timer);
```

to get ss_timer_callback function out of investigation - i've commented out its body - it's only doing single printk

I test it with iperf tool, everything works fine for single thread, but when i invoke it with "-P 2" for 2 parallel client threads whole system crashes instantly.

I believe that the problem lies in multiple "add_timer" calls in parallel. I realise my take on this might be wrong altogether so i'd really appreciate someone more experienced to guide me.

Comment: At any time single **instance** of `struct timer_list` object can be added to timer list at most **once**. If you want two timers, you need two instances of `struct timer_list`. (That is, you need no a global variable, but a variable per TCP session).

Comment: Ok, that's valuable information. Unfortunately my problem still stands - moving declaration and initialization of timer inside TCP session init function crashes kernel when transmission is over but timer hasn't expired yet, another thing is that i can't really delete timer from anywhere since it's created locally.

In recovery mode i can see the error just before everything crashes, it says "kernel panic run_timer_softirq". Is there another way to have multiple timers run for each thread establishing TCP connection separately? Some type o timer that can be spawned multiple times maybe?

Comment: When you call `add_timer` for `struct timer_list` instance, that instance becomes **part of the timer list**, and its fields (`.function`, `.data` and `.expires`) are used when the timer expires. This is why you cannot use the same instance for two timers in a list at once - when you fill instance for the second timer, you rewrite its fields which are used by the first timer. You may allocate new `struct timer_list` instance when you need the second timer. But in any case you should delete the timer which is no longer used.

Comment: I've redesigned the whole thing, the timer is initialized at module registration and deleted on unregister, what makes it run whenever tcp session is created is an atomic flag at the beggining of callback function. Everything works as it should. Whanks a lot @Tsyvarev your comments really made me think in another way :)